# Combine Bit Fields

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to get these bits in the right order

my goal:

given the following inputs

```
char id = 0x02; //in binary => 0010
char somethingElse = 0xF; //in binary => 1111
```

how can I obtain the following output

```
char result = ?; //in binary 0010 1111 (id somethingElse)
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question?  It is not clear at all what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char id = 0x02; //in binary => 0010
char somethingElse = 0xF; //in binary => 1111

char result = (id<<4) | somethingElse;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simpler shift operation unless the bits are often modified independently (like bits in the header of some format specification). In this case I would use a combination of a union and bit field. Here is a little program to do this

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        union {
            struct {
                unsigned char id:4;
                unsigned char somethingElse:4;
            } split;
            unsigned char combined;
        } value;

        value.split.id = 0x02;
        value.split.somethingElse = 0xF;

        NSLog(@"%02X", value.combined); // Outputs F2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You might want to invert the order of id and somethingElse if this is not the order you want.